# Getting Server Error When Deployed To Server

Tags: html, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am getting a

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

exception when I deployed my program / website to the server-

The code that is causing the error is

```
protected void updateDropdown()
{
    string connectionString ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["kipatel_CS3340ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand dbQuery = new SqlCommand("SELECT Patients.LastName, Patients.PatientID FROM Patients", connection);
```

the error is at

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["kipatel_CS3340ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

that is what the server is giving me the error

The link to my site is https://lucius.valdosta.edu/kipatel/hw04/ please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have the correct connection string. 
Open your `web.config` and check if the value of the key `kipatel_CS3340ConnectionString` is correct.

And finally to have this working in both local/remote server, change

```
     string connectionString ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["kipatel_CS3340ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

to

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager
                       .ConnectionStrings["kipatel_CS3340ConnectionString"]
                       .ToString();
```

Comment: thanks you it was in my web.config that was wrong i fixed it and it is now working thanks you